# Show that $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is nowhere analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let us consider the function:

$f(z)=\bar{z}$. How can I show that this function is nowhere analytic?

It is evident that

$$\lim\limits _{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$$

does not exist, but I am stuck to show it is not differentiable on the entire plane.

Comment: You get the same limit if you write down the definition of the derivative at an arbitrary point $a\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: Show that there is no open set on which the Cauchy-Riemann equations are verified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps easiest is to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  $\bar{z} = x-iy$, so $u = x$ and $v=-y$ and so $u_x = 1$, $u_y = 0$, $v_x=0$, $v_y = -1$, so the equations are never satisfied, at any point.

Your technique will also work at any point.  Think of the complex derivative in the alternative way:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}
$$

Comment: @JL, thank you very much(+1)